# Error starting pyspark with options (Without Spack packages)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

can anyone tell me why I'm getting the errors below ? According to the 
README for the pyspark-cassandra connector, what I am trying below should work (without Spark packages): https://github.com/TargetHolding/pyspark-cassandra

```
$ pyspark_jar="$HOME/devel/sandbox/Learning/Spark/pyspark-cassandra/target/scala-2.10/pyspark-cassandra-assembly-0.2.2.jar"

$ pyspark_egg="$HOME/devel/sandbox/Learning/Spark/pyspark-cassandra/target/pyspark_cassandra-0.2.2-py2.7.egg"
$ pyspark --jars $pyspark_jar --py_files $pyspark_egg --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=localhost
```

This results in:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pyspark does not support any application options.
at org.apache.spark.launcher.CommandBuilderUtils.checkArgument(CommandBuilderUtils.java:222)
at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.buildPySparkShellCommand(SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.java:239)
at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.buildCommand(SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.java:113)
at org.apache.spark.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:74)
```

Comment: Figured out the problem. I needed to use

    `--py-files`

instead of

    `--py_files`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured out the problem. I needed to use

```
--py-files
```

instead of

```
--py_files
```